# Should I use vm or set the maxmemory with Redis' 2.4

Tags: database, redis, nosql

In **redis 2.4** the `vm-enabled no` is the default, so I am using redis as database (not cache), and maybe occasionally the  db size is larger than the memory, should I enable it?

Or should I enfore `maxmemory` to prevent data loss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://redis.io/topics/faq

> What happens if Redis runs out of memory?
>
> With modern operating
> systems malloc() returning NULL is not common, usually the server will
> start swapping and Redis performances will degrade so you'll probably
> notice there is something wrong. The INFO command will report the
> amount of memory Redis is using so you can write scripts that monitor
> your Redis servers checking for critical conditions. Alternatively can
> use the "maxmemory" option in the config file to put a limit to the
> memory Redis can use. If this limit is reached Redis will start to
> reply with an error to write commands (but will continue to accept
> read-only commands), or you can configure it to evict keys when the
> max memory limit is reached in the case you are using Redis for
> caching.

Don't do anything...? At worst you get a serious performance degradation from swapping but that's it? You have error handling in your application anyways, don't you?

Comment: So just leave the default, and enabled a decent SWAP partition on my Linux seems to be a good fit?

Comment: That's what the manual suggests, yes.